# I have a data frame that I need to add 2 new categories in existing columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe example shown below. I need to add a new category 3 in Facility and a new category 4 in product. For the added categories i would like to either add NA to the mean or zero.

| name | product | Facility | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0.5 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 0.3 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0.2 |
| A | 3 | 1 | 0.1 |
| A | 3 | 2 | 2.5 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 2.3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 5.2 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 1.2 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 8.0 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 2.3 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 0.9 |

Can you please assist me on how i can add the new categories? I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: you should look at [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) function

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A'],'product':[1],'facility':[4], 'mean':[2]})

new_row = ['C',4,5,0]

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.values, new_row] ), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

[image]